# Pari/GP: user defined functions

Tags: pari-gp

I have defined a couple of functions of arity 1, say `func1(-)` and `func2(-)`. I have tested them and seen that they actually do what they are supposed to.

I wish to define a third function, say `func3(-)`, that outputs the difference of `func1(-)` and `func2(-)`. This is what I do

```
func3(k) = {j=func1(k)-func2(k); print(j)}
```

Nevertheless, it doesn't return what it ought to. Let us suppose that `func1(5)` outputs 10 and `func2(5)` outputs 2. Then, `func3(5)` ought to output an 8, right? It returns instead the output of `func1(5)` in one row, the output of `func2(2)` in another row, and then a zero (even though the difference of the corresponding outputs is not 0).

Do you know what's wrong with the definition of `func3(-)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A GP user function returns the last evaluated value. Here, it's the resut of
the 'print(j)' command, which prints j (side effect) and returns 'void',
which is typecast to 0 when it must be given a value, as here.

```
f1(x) = 10
f2(x) = 2
f3(x) = f1(x) - f2(x)
```

correctly returns 8. You didn't give the code for your func1 / func2
functions, but I expect you included a 'print' statement, maybe expecting it
to return a value. That's why you get outputs on different rows, before the 0.

If you don't like this 'return-last-evaluation-result' behaviour, you can use
explicit 'return (result)' statements.